# Problem using xargs --max-args --replace with default delimiter

Tags: linux, xargs, gnu

This works as expected:

```
$ echo a b c | xargs --replace="{}" echo x "{}" y
x a b c y
```

This does too:

```
$ echo a b c | xargs --max-args=1 echo x
x a
x b
x c
```

But this doesn't work as expected:

```
$ echo a b c | xargs --max-args=1 --replace="{}" echo x "{}" y
x a b c y
```

And neither does this:

```
$ echo a b c | xargs --delimiter=' ' --max-args=1 --replace="{}" echo x "{}" y
x a y
x b y
x c
 y
```

I expected this output:

```
x a y
x b y
x c y
```

As a workaround, I am using printf and two xargs, but that is ugly:

```
$ echo a b c | xargs printf '%s\0' | \
> xargs --null --max-args=1 --replace="{}" echo x "{}" y
x a y
x b y
x c y
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/xargs.html), `xargs` should run the given utility with arguments delimited by either spaces or newlines, and this is what happens in the two first examples of yours.

However, when `--replace` (or `-I`) is used, only newlines will delimit arguments. The remedy is to give `xargs` arguments on separate lines:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' a b c | xargs --max-args=1 --replace="{}" echo x "{}" y
x a y
x b y
x c y
```

Using POSIX options:

```bash
printf '%s\n' a b c | xargs -n 1 -I "{}" echo x "{}" y
```

Here, I give `xargs` not one line but three.  It takes one line (at most) and executes the utility with that as the argument.

Note also that `-n 1` (or `--max-args=1`) in the above is not needed as it's the number of replacements made by `-I` that determines the number of arguments used:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' a b c | xargs -I "{}" echo x "{}" y
x a y
x b y
x c y
```

In fact, the Rationale section of the POSIX spec on `xargs` says (my emphasis)

> **The `-I`, `-L`, and `-n` options are mutually-exclusive**. Some implementations use the last one specified if more than one is given on a command line; other implementations treat combinations of the options in different ways.

While testing this, I noticed that OpenBSD's version of `xargs` will do the the following if `-n` and `-I` are used together:

```bash
$ echo  a b c | xargs -n 1  -I "{}" echo x "{}" y
x a y
x b y
x c y
```

This is different from what GNU coreutils' `xargs` does (which produces `x a b c y`). This is due to the implementation accepting spaces as argument delimiter with `-n`, even though `-I` is used. So, don't use `-I` and `-n` together (it's not needed anyway).

Comment: That behaviour (that newline should be the only delimiter with -I) is documented in the GNU `xargs` documentation and the POSIX specification (under XSI, so it's not surprising that OpenBSD doesn't comply there). In any case, using `-n` with `-I` makes little sense as `{}` is to replace **one** argument anyway.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah. I was looking too closely at `-n` and not at `-I`. Will update.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It seems that OpenBSD's `xargs` does the correct thing if `-I` and `-n` is not mixed. I rewrote that part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the POSIX `xargs`. The way I read it, it's nearly useless, as it says that `-I`, `-L` and `-n` are mutually exclusive. Glad we have the GNU version. // Actually `echo a b c` was a placeholder for any command that generates multiple space-separated parameters, hence why I used `| xargs printf` instead of using `printf` directly. // I'm still digesting your post. You've written that OpenBSD `xargs` will do the *wrong* thing, is that a typo?

Comment: @PedroGimeno No typo. It's the wrong output since it uses the three letters as separate arguments even though `-I` is used. It does, however, do the right thing if `-n` is _not_ used. As you say, `-I` and `-n` are mutually exclusive, and an implementation may choose to handle this situation in any way it wants, so "wrong" is maybe the wrong word...

Comment: @PedroGimeno There, better wording.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If I'm reading the specs right, the implementation may choose how to handle conflicting arguments to `xargs`. It only so happens that coerutils and OpenBSD chooses to do different things.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I get it now. The moral of this story for me is: either use the ugly workaround, or, even better, replace it with a `for` loop in Bash when possible (which was what i was trying to avoid, but it seems to be the best approach in my use case).

Comment: @PedroGimeno At the moment, only you can tell whether that's good or not :-)

Answer (score 5):

One work around I found was feeding the output of `--max-args` to `--replace` like this:

```bash
echo a b c | xargs -n 1 | xargs -i echo firstPart {} secondPart
```

This will output.

```
firstPart a secondPart
firstPart b secondPart
firstPart b secondPart
```

I guess it's basically looping through the input with `--max-args` and adding the new line character by default.

Comment: Re: "I guess": consider explaining why does this workaround indeed work.